# How can I create hexagons in react with using tailwind?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, tailwind-css

I want to create hexagons like below the picture. But it's more than 3 hours I can no figure out how can I do that. I have tried different libraries and etc.

Hexagons

[image: 1]

I want to create this type of hexagons.

Comment: Maybe use svg ?

Answer (score 4):

You could create them yourself, and then position them absolutely inside a relative container.
This code should get you started, and it can easily be converted to react code if you want.

This creates a set of hexagon using clipping paths, and then apply a SVG filter to round the edges.

```css
.container {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}

.hex {
  display: inline-block;
  filter: url('#goo');
  color: darkBlue;
  width: 35%;
  position: absolute;
}

.hex::before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background: currentColor;
  padding-top: 86.6%;
  /* 100%*cos(30) */
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0%, 75% 0%, 100% 50%, 75% 100%, 25% 100%, 0% 50%);
}

.pos0 {
  top: 0%;
  left: 30%;
}

.pos1 {
  top: 17%;
  left: 0%;
}

.pos2 {
  top: 17%;
  left: 60%;
}

.pos3 {
  top: 34%;
  left: 30%;
}

.pos4 {
  top: 51%;
  left: 0%;
}

.pos5 {
  top: 68%;
  left: 30%;
}

.pos6 {
  top: 51%;
  left: 60%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="hex pos0"></div>
  <div class="hex pos1"></div>
  <div class="hex pos2"></div>
  <div class="hex pos3"></div>
  <div class="hex pos4"></div>
  <div class="hex pos5"></div>
  <div class="hex pos6"></div>
</div>



<svg style="visibility: hidden; position: absolute;" width="0" height="0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">
  <defs>
        <filter id="goo"><feGaussianBlur in="SourceGraphic" stdDeviation="4" result="blur" />    
            <feColorMatrix in="blur" mode="matrix" values="1 0 0 0 0  0 1 0 0 0  0 0 1 0 0  0 0 0 19 -9" result="goo" />
            <feComposite in="SourceGraphic" in2="goo" operator="atop"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
</svg>
```

This hexagon cluster is placed within a responsive container, change the `.container` width and height to change the size.

Comment: you are legend bro. I just figure out how to do it but how can I make them responsive ?

Comment: What do you mean by responsive? Resizeable, or interactable. I have updated the answer to resize within the container.

Comment: I can create interactable components without any problem. Just couldn't figure out how to create hexagon and place other hexagons around it. This answers is very useful thank you for everything :)